# Row Key Being displayed as `\x00\x00\x00\x03` rather than integer

Tags: scala, hbase

```
lines.foreachRDD{rdd =>
                        val temp = rdd.map(_._2)
                        temp.collect().foreach(a => {
                                if (a == "Insurance:dental") {
                                        val thePut = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(3))
                                        thePut.add(Bytes.toBytes("insurance"), Bytes.toBytes("dental"), Bytes.toBytes("metlife"))
                                        table.put(thePut)
                                }
                        })
                }
```

In the scala code above the `row key` is `val thePut = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(3))`. For some reason when I save it to `HBase` it saves the row key like `\x00\x00\x00\x03` instead of the integer `3`.

Am I doing something wrong here: `val thePut = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(3))`? Since everything in `HBase` is a byte array so I converted the integer 3 to a byte in the above code.

Comment: The title seems to have nothing to do with the question?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Ok I have changed the title. Sorry about that. Do you happen to know what the problem is?

Comment: No idea, sorry. I'd say clearly it's writing out the binary representation of a 32-bit integer, though

Comment: Yeah that is what I was thinking. I will have to research more on that now... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it in the hbase shell itself. I just had to do `deleteall 'TABLE_NAME', "\x00\x00\x00\x03"` Using the double quotes surrounding the `\x00\x00\x00\x03` (`\x00\x00\x00\x03` was my row key) preserves the original data type of that row key (which is a 32 bit representation of the integer 3). So to delete that entire row, use `deleteall` and to preserve the row key datatype, use `""`.